# How can I handle a reactive form and fields validation in a situation where some form fields are created dynamically?

Tags: angular, primeng, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

I am working on an Angular project using PrimeNG and I have the following problem to solve using reactive form.

Basically in my HTML I have something that rendering this:

[image]

Basically the interested field is the **Commessa** field representing a "project order ID". I think that sometimes it is used the WSS word (Work Breakdown Structure) in English-speaking business language.

And this is the code that I am using at the moment:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-2">
    <p>Commessa</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-10">
    <input id="commessa" class="p-invalid" aria-describedby="commessa-help" formControlName="commessa" type="text" pInputText required/>
    <i class="pi pi-plus-circle"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

So when the form is "submitted" (it is not a real submission) in my TypeScript component code I have this **orderForm** object:

```
orderForm: FormGroup;
```

that is initialized into the **ngOnInit()** setting the validation rules for all the fields defined in my form:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.orderFormValues = new OrderFormValues();

    console.log("orderFormValues VALUES: " + this.orderFormValues.statoOrdine);

    this.orderForm = this.fb.group({
    idOrdine: [null, [Validators.required]],
    dataInserimentoOrdine: [new Date(), [Validators.required]],
    statoOrdine: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5)]],
    commessa: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5)]],
    CIG: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.pattern("^[a-zA-Z0-9]{10}$")]],
    dataInizioAttivita: [null, [Validators.required]],
    dataFineAttivita: [null, [Validators.required]],
    referente: [null, [Validators.required]],
    ruoloReferente: [null, [Validators.required]],
    tipologiaDiPartecipazione: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5)]],
    quotaPercentualeDiRTI: [null, [Validators.max(100)]],

    cliente: [null, [Validators.required]],
    vatCliente: [null, [Validators.required]],
    clienteFinale: [null, []],
    vatClienteFinale: [null, []],

    tipologiaContratto: [null, []],
    importoContratto: [null, [Validators.required]],
    linkContratto: [null, [Validators.required]],
    dataSottoscrizioneContratto: [null, [Validators.required]],

    nomeSocieta: [null, [Validators.required]],
    vatSocieta: [null, []],
    buName: [null, [Validators.required]],

    presenzaAQ: [false, [Validators.required]],
    linkIdentificativoAQ: [null, []],
    accordoQuadro: [null, []],
    residuoAccordoQuadro: [null, []],
    compagineDiAQ: [null, []]
});
```

Until now I only add a single "Commessa" field (because the use case foresaw a single ID order for the single order represented by my form). But now things are changed and I have to handle multiple ID orders for a single order. So I need n "Commessa" fields.

My original idea in fact was to add the **+** icon:

```
<i class="pi pi-plus-circle"></i>
```

Clicking this icon the FE will add a new field to insert a second, third,...n field for a new ID order.

The problem is how to handle validation and coordination with my reactive form in this case? In fact at the moment I have to statically define the fields that will be associated to my **FormGroup** object via **formControlName** attribute in the HTML.

In the specific case at the moment I have that:

```
 <input id="commessa" class="p-invalid" aria-describedby="commessa-help" formControlName="commessa" type="text" pInputText required/>
```

is related to the following **FormGroup** element using the **formControlName="commessa"**

```
commessa: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5)]],
```

in this way when the user fill the **Commessa** field in the front end the **commessa** element in the **FormGroup** is valorized and it checks if the inserted value is valid or not.

So I was think to add a new input field clicking the **+** button (for example having **id="commessa_2"** and **formControlName="commessa_2"** but then how to handle this situation via backend? Is it possible to add a new element with its validator into my **FormGroup** object?

What could be a good strategy to handle this kind of dynamic situation when you don't know the exact number of fields in a form? (when some fields can be created dynamically as in this case).

How can I solve this problem in a smart way?

Comment: Read the docs: https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl. Do some research.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Using Reactive form **[FormArray](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray)**, we can achieve the requirement.*

***Please refer to the below example***
[image]
**Example code:**

***app.component.ts***

```ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup, FormArray, Validators, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }
  orderForm = this.fb.group({
    idOrdine: [null, [Validators.required]],
    commessaList: new FormArray([
      new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5)])
    ])
  });

  get commessaList(): FormArray {
    return this.orderForm.get('commessaList') as FormArray;
  }
  onFormSubmit(): void {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.commessaList.length; i++) {
      console.log(this.commessaList.at(i).value);
    }
  }
  addCommessaField() {
    this.commessaList.push(new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5)]));
  }

  deleteCommessaField(index: number) {
    if (this.commessaList.length !== 1) {
      this.commessaList.removeAt(index);
    }
    console.log(this.commessaList.length);
  }
}
```

***app.component.html***

```html
<div class="container">
  <br>
  <form [formGroup]="orderForm" (ngSubmit)="onFormSubmit()">
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="idOrdine" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Id Ordine</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" formControlName="idOrdine"
          [ngClass]="{'error':orderForm.controls.idOrdine.invalid && orderForm.controls.idOrdine.touched}"
          class="form-control" id="idOrdine">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div formArrayName="commessaList">
      <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="commessa" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Commessa</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <ng-container *ngFor="let commessa of commessaList.controls; index as idx">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-8">
                <input type="text" [ngClass]="{'error':commessa.invalid && commessa.touched}" [formControlName]="idx"
                  class="form-control" id="commessa">
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-2">
                <button type="button" *ngIf="idx===0" (click)="addCommessaField()" class="btn btn-success"
                  [ngClass]="'pad'"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>

                <button (click)="deleteCommessaField(idx)" *ngIf="idx!==0" class="btn btn-danger">
                  <i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </ng-container>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="orderForm.invalid">Save</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

***app.component.css***

```css
.container {
    margin: 100px;
}
.error{
    background-color: red;
    color:#FFF;
  }

  .row {
    display: flex;
    align-items: baseline;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Angular provides [Form Array](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray) for this. So instead of creating multiple fields in the Form Group. You can set the commessa field as a [Form Array](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray). Which allows field to be dynamically inserted into it as an array.

Comment: Tnx, now I will try to understand the documentation. Onlu a thing: do you think that it is possible use it avoiding to change my intere FormGroup architecture?